# Minimalist Visual Studio 2012

Tags: html, visual-studio, user-interface

Is there a way to hide the breadcrumbs' bar on html editor and toolbar buttons (Error List, Output, etc)? I like my editor as clean as posible.

Also if there is a way to autohide the status bar when I'm not building, it would be helpful. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I worked on Visual Studio)

The "HTML Designer/Editor"-mode in Visual Studio does not let you hide the breadcrumb bar, however you can force-open HTML files in the XML editor and so not have the breadcrumb bar, but it's only ~20px of vertical space, this shouldn't be an issue unless you're using a small display. You can select the XML editor by choosing "Open with..." when opening a file.

As for the Window tabs (Error List, Output, etc): if you show the windows and then click the Pin button, you can then tear-off the entire window set and close them all at once with the close button, they will then re-appear if you manually choose to or keep them as floating windows.

The status bar can be hidden by going Tools > Options > Environment > Show Status Bar, however I don't believe there is no way to have it automatically show/hide if content changes.

However, why are you wanting to hide these UI elements? The vertical space the Status bar and Window tabs consume is about 55px at 96dpi, even at 1366x768 it isn't enough screen-space to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

The status bar can be hidden, but I want it to show only if the message (in the image is "Ready") changes so I can see what is happening in the build process.

And why I want them hidden? After using tools such as SublimeText and PhpStorm I grew fond of minimalism in my editor.

Comment: @Hrodger I've updated my question re: the status bar, I forgot about that option. Remember that Visual Studio does not try to be a minimalist product, if we tried I'm sure the community would be up-in-arms. I can only suggest that you shouldn't try to force VS into being something that it isn't.